# Cassandra: Ignore timezone for timestamp value

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

I've written a program that reads a file containing the date (in yyyy/MM/dd format) and uses the Datastax Java Driver to read the date and add it to a cassandra table.
So for instance, if my record contains a date value of '2010/06/01', then this date value gets converted into a date object (using the SimpleDateFormat class).

However, when I view the data (containing the date) in the database, I see that the date (which in the cassandra table is a timestamp type) shows the following:

```
  2010-06-01 00:00:00+0100
```

The issue here is that I don't want the timestamp to have "+0100" (to indicate that this is british summer time), rather I'd want to store the date just as "2010-06-01 00:00:00+0000".

I've done the following to my program to try and 'ignore' the timezone by doing the following:

```
    SimpleTimeZone tz = new SimpleTimeZone(0, "Out Timezone");             
    TimeZone.setDefault(tz);  
    String dateStringFromFile = "2010/06/01";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date theDate = sdf.parse(dateStringFromFile);
```

...Now when I add debug statements to my program, I can see that the date shows "2010-06-01 00:00:00+0000" on my log file (this is right for me). However when i see the date stored in Cassandra, i still see that the date shows as
"2010-06-01 00:00:00+0100" and not "2010-06-01 00:00:00+0000".

Is there anything on the cassandra side that I would have to change or update to ignore the timezone (i.e. not put +0100 on the date and to put +0000), so that the timestamp shows as "2010-06-01 00:00:00+0000"?

Please note that I am running Cassandra 3.0.5 on a Docker VM (Centos linux), Java 8.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you view your data. If by cqlsh then change the UI section of cqlshrc file

Comment: Hi, I use DBeaver (which is a UI program).

Comment: That uitility might be doing it. Check through your java code or cqlsh

Comment: Hi, in addition to using DBeaver, I have used CQLSH and Datastax DevCenter. I can see that the issue still persists regardless of what utility I use. I have also looked through my Java code and after adding debug statements to the code in my previous post, all the dates in the Java Program are showing as GMT (with +0000, not +0100). However cassandra is still storing it as +0100. Could this be a timezone setting in Cassandra that needs to be changed? or perhaps on the Linux OS level? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If you insert the data from cqlsh do you still see the problem when you read it? Sample code and create statement would help if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I took the advice of manually adding an insert statement to DBeaver (and CQLSH) - the query i'm inserting is INSERT INTO testkeyspace.table1(filename, location, recorddate ) VALUES ('hello.txt', 'driveC', '2010-06-01'); After inserting this statement, I see the value "2010-06-01 00:00:00+0100". So its not to do with my java program, but perhaps a setting in cassandra?

Comment: Change the ui setting in cqlshrc. This file has timezone setting

Comment: Hi, I've taken a copy of cqlshrc.sample and after researching, I have to add this file (renaming it as 'cqlshrc') in a hidden dir called "~/.cassandra". However are you able to specify the exact entry into the [ui] setting for the timezone? (i'm struggling to find this out on the web). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has been sorted out. Nothing to do with cqlshrc. Its to do with forcing the timezone as 0 (like the code in the original post) and getting the time in milliseconds and writing that to the database - (which is a timestamp type column)